# How do I center an image for mobile screens (using HTML)?

Tags: html, css, mobile, screen, responsive

I'm working on a work project using an interface which allows only HTML editing. Users viewing the pages I'm creating will view them from Mobile devices. The images I'm trying to place are above a paragraph. All I need is for the image to be centered.

I've created an example which looks centered on a larger screen, but moves the image slightly to the right on smaller screens. Could someone let me know what's going wrong here?

```css
.image {
  width: 382px;
  height: 135px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<img src="image.jpg">
```

Edit: in my end-of-day frenzy I forgot to mention I've already assigned a class: "image".

Comment: With the code provided (assuming the image has a class of image), I wouldn't see what would move the image to the right on smaller screens - are thre any media queries / other style affecting the image, or are there other elements next to it that could affect it's position?

Comment: You hqve defined style propertiee but you didnot defined tha class, so you need to add class="image" to you img attribute. Or you can add the style to your img attribut instate of .image

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply your styles to your image

```css
.image {
  width: 382px;
  height: 135px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<img src="image.jpg" class="image">
```

Answer (score 1):

When you put the dot (.) in front, it registers that as a class name. So just add a class named image to the img tag.

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="image">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 `.center-div{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need @media to achieve this. media will change css style based on screen size. by the way either add class **image** to your image or just use **img** in css style sheet, which is not recommended to use only **img** because it will effect all other imgs so just use

HTML:

```
<img class="image" src="...">
```

CSS:

```
//you can change min-width and max-width based on your desires
@media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.image {
   text-align: center
   //you can add any other style in here
   }
}
```